# How open docker settings on windows?

Tags: windows-10, docker-for-windows

[Here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly) is screenshot for docker settings:

[image]

But how open it on windows? When I search for "docker" I only see "Docker for windows" shorcut which just check whether docker service have been already run or do nothing otherwise. There are no other icons or applciation with such name. Any ideas?

Screenshot with docker search:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first carefully read the documentation :
[Get started with Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/).

The section "Docker Settings dialog" says this :

1. Open the Docker for Windows menu by right-clicking the Docker icon in the Notifications area (or System tray):

[image]

2. Select Settings... to open the Settings dialog:

[image]

Comment: For me, it's showing 'Settings' window with disabled everything on it and some buffering wheel with 'Docker updating' text in bottom left corner. And I cannot get rid of it. what can be root cause behind it ?

Comment: @Vebbie: Not enough information. I suggest starting a new post detailing how you installed Docker, the involved user accounts, and a screenshot of the menu.

Comment: sure. will do that. Thanks :)